# Trying to modify a bubble sort in a very specific way for an array of random doubles

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm pretty novice at C and I'm trying to follow my assignment's specific instructions on how to modify a bubble sort in the way my professor wants.

Basically what we're doing is creating an array of doubles with random values, and then copying and sorting that array into a NEW array using several sorting methods.

I've got the array and random numbers down fine, but I can't tell if I've modified this bubble sort correctly. The assignment's instructions state:

> The modified bubble sort involves an inner and an outer loop. The outer loop increments its counter/index (***i***, for discussion) from ***0*** to ***n – 1***, where ***n*** is the number of elements in the array to be sorted. The inner loop increments its counter/index from ***i + 1*** to ***n***, and tests each element in that range against the array element at ***i*** to identify the smallest element in the range. After this inner loop exits, and while still in the outer loop, if an element smaller than that at position ***i*** is found, the value at that location is swapped with the value at ***i***, otherwise no action is taken and the outer loop repeats as required.

This is my code for the bubble sort:

```
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
{
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (arrayB[j] < arrayB[i])
        {
            value = arrayB[i];
            arrayB[i] = arrayB[j];
            arrayB[j] = value;
        }                             
    }
}
```

This code sorts the array correctly, but I don't know how to tell if that's because it's just a normal bubble sort or because I modified it the way I was supposed to. I don't know how bubble sorts typically look in C so I can't tell if this is a modified version or not.

I would also like to clarify that this is NOT supposed to be C++ code, but plain old C.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The description sounds like selection sort while the code is like bubble sort

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description, I think what you need is [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).

Unlike in the case of bubble sort where swapping is done the moment an out of order pair of numbers is encountered, swapping is done at most one time for an iteration of the outer loop.

You will need a variable like `smallIndex` to store the index with value less than `arrayB[i]`.
Let this variable be given value `i` before entering the inner loop within which value of `smallIndex` is modified if necessary.

After coming out of inner loop but before the end of current iteration of outer loop, check if `smallIndex` is still `i` and if not swap `arrayB[i]` and `arrayB[smallIndex]`.

The code may be like

```
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
{
    smallIndex = i;
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (arrayB[j] < arrayB[smallIndex])
        {
            smallIndex=j;
        }
    }
    if(smallIndex!=i)
    {
        value = arrayB[i];
        arrayB[i] = arrayB[smallIndex];
        arrayB[bigIndex] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ordinary bubble sort, because you're doing the swaps in the inner loop.

The instructions say you're supposed to do the swap *after* the innner loop completes. The inner loop is just supposed to find the smallest element in the range `i to n`. Then after the inner loop completes, you swap that element with `i`.

```
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
{
    int smallest_index = i;
    int smallest = arrayB[i];
    // find smallest element in range [i, n)
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (arrayB[j] < smallest)
        {
            smallest = arrayB[j];
            smallest_index = j;
        }
    }
    // swap it with i if necessary
    if (smallest_index != i) {
        arrayB[smallest_index] = arrayB[i];
        arrayB[i] = smallest;
    }
}
```